# Ear-decompositions

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $2$-connected graph which is not a cycle and let $e$ be an edge of G.

I have to show that there are ear-decompositions $C,P_1,...,P_k$ and $\hat{C},\hat{P_1},...,\hat{P_k}$ of $G$ such that edge $e$ lies on $C$ and on $\hat{P_1}$.

I would really appreciate any help, because I am lost on this problem..

Answer (score 1):

Start by showing that there is an ear-decomposition $C^\prime,P^\prime_1,\dots,P^\prime_k$, using the fact that the graph is 2-connected.

If $e$ is in $C^\prime$, rename everything as $C, P_1, \dots, P_k$, and see if you can modify the decomposition to $\hat{C},\hat{P}_1,\dots, \hat{P_k}$ in a way that you swap out the cycle so that $e$ is in $\hat{P}_1$.

If $e$ is in $P^\prime_i$, rename everything to $\hat{C},\hat{P}_1,\dots, \hat{P_k}$, where $P^\prime_i = \hat{P}_1$, and see how you can modify the decomposition to $C, P_1, \dots, P_k$ so that $e$ is in $C$.